# Why doesn't this css3 for vertical centering work in IE11? Works in Firefox, Chrome & Edge

Tags: html, css

This is a link from [CSS Secrets: Better Solutions to Everyday Web Design Problems](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=css%20secrets) book which will center any content using css3 only and without specifying a width. Link: http://dabblet.com/gist/8aa9aa04ee57f479c513. IE 11 supports the flex model, vh unit & box-sizing. Why isn't the vertical centering part working in IE11? It works in Chrome, Firefox & Edge.

I am also trying to make it work in IE10- using polyfills and I haven't had success. If anyone manages this to work in these lower versions of IE, please post your solution.

Comment: here is a good article https://alastairc.ac/2014/08/flexbox-ie11-bugs/ maybe it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example to work IE11 expects HTML, BODY and MAIN to have a defined height. One could debate about which browser is correct and which has a hidden feature. I prefer FF developer Edition for coding and testing as it seems to be closests to W3C.

Check the snippet for add's...

```css
/**
 * Vertical centering - Flexbox solution
 */

html, body { height: 100% } /* ADDED */

* {
  margin: 0
}
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
main {
  height: 100px; /* ADDED */
  padding: 1em 2em;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #655;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  font-size: 150%;
}
body {
  background: #fb3;
  font: 100%/1.5 sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Am I centered yet?</h1>
    <p>Center me, please!</p>
</main>
```